# Is calling an executable from JavaScript in a browser via a RESTful service viable?

Tags: javascript, rest, browser

I have a web app running in a browser on the client machine.
I need to call an executable on the same machine.
JavaScript can't do this as far as I know, so I was thinking about installing a small RESTful service (e. g. a Spring Boot Java application) on the client machine which can accept requests from the browser and call the executable.

Browser --HTTP request--> REST service --call--> executable

Installing another application on the machine seems a bit too much for such a simple thing, but I can't think of an easier way. Is this a viable solution? Am I overlooking something? (Re-writing the executable to just work as a RESTful service itself is not an option, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js to call it. For example you can use this workflow,

Browser javascript code -> make a ajax / fetch api request to you service end point ( this service endpoint can be created using express ) -> then when you hit this end point you can use node.js libraries to call the executable you wish in the express callback function and return a response like executable was executed.